# Does JDOM have any support for ID and IDREF?

Tags: java, xml, jdom

```
<!DOCTYPE inventory [
<!ELEMENT book (title,author)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST book year CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST book myId ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST book myIdRef IDREF #IMPLIED>
]>
<inventory>
    <book year="2000" myId="1">
        <title>Snow Crash</title>
        <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
    </book>
    <book myId="3" myIdRef="1"/>
</inventory>
```

Does JDom has ability to do something like:

```
Element root = doc.getRootElement();
List children = root.getChildren();
for(Object node:children){
  Element book = (Element) node;
  System.out.println(book.getAttributeValue("year")); 
}

/*
  So print:
    2000 
    2000
*/
```

Or any other facility related to ID and IDREF??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.google.com/?q=jdom+idref) I found something to answer your question. As far as I understand, jDom does not have a direct support but there's the `org.jdom.contrib.ids` package that

> Provides support for Documents
>   allowing looking up elements using the
>   value of their ID attribute

I found the library [here](http://www.ee.buu.ac.th/~acitl/project/2007/java/JDOM/jdom-contrib-1.0/) (it's not the main location, maybe somebody else knows the repository URL for that library)